# geoserver to leaflet via jsonp

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geojson, ajax

Please somebody help because I am on the edge of madness:) I have no idea what is wrong with my code...
Only what I want is adding layers to my leaflet map: 1 point layer, 1 line, and one polygon. They all come from geoserver. here is the map: http://gis.xyz/ngrid.html
So I have added 3 layers, I can see only two, and in the layer control this two layer are swapped. It would be great if somebody look at the example, or show me a working example...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your question is adequate because it's not really specific or clear. Any way I suggest you:

1) Simplify your code. Start with just one layer e check if it is working. Add a second and check again. Do the same for all your layers.

2) Do not let you error option in the ajax function empty. At least include a console.log so you can see what is going on.

3) Try to keep your javascript code apart from your html file. It will improve the legibility of your code.

4) Try to use firebug to monitor the loading. I used in your page and saw some messages that could be related to your problem.

That's it. Good luck!